# Overlaying an image

Tags: html, css

The best way I can describe it is by showing.

```
<div style="position: absolute; z-index:100">This is in background</div> 
<div style="position: absolute; z-index:5000">This is in foreground</div>
```

I thought maybe it could be used in a similar way, but i think im too stupid.

I think I got the rotation part, I have seen a lot of css codes on the internet for that. So if i can just get some help and find a way to just place the banner on top of my container, that would be a huge help!

I want it to be ontop of this:

What I want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/71Kz2.jpg
Banner: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRvbz.jpg

I tried this:

```html
    <div id=container>
    <div style="clear:both; height: 40px"></div>
    <div class=box_highlight>
    <h2 style="text-align: center; color: #000000;">Bestellen Sie jetzt!</h2>
    <center>
    <h3>
    <ul style="padding-top:30px">
    <li>- Blick ins Olympiastadion München</li>
    <li>- Hochwertiges, doppellagiges Polyester-Pongée-Material</li>
    <li>- Durchmesser ca. 140 cm</li>
    <li>- Stabiles Metallgestänge</li>
    </ul>
    </h3>
    <h2 class="priceSize" style="text-align: center; color: #000000" ><br>
    Preis: 24,90 €
    </h2>
    
    <h3>
    <ul style="padding-top:30px">
    <li>zzgl. Versandkosten: Deutschland: 4,95 € / EU: 14,95 € / Schweiz: 22,70 € </li>
    </ul>
    </h3>
    </center>
    <br>
    </div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div id=container style="position:relative;">
<div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left:-50px; transform:rotate(-45deg)"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/LTUZE58.jpg" alt="" width="300"></div>
<div style="clear:both; height: 40px"></div>
<div class=box_highlight>
<h2 style="text-align: center; color: #000000;">Bestellen Sie jetzt!</h2>
<center>
<h3>
<ul style="padding-top:30px">
<li>-   Blick ins Olympiastadion München</li>
<li>-   Hochwertiges, doppellagiges Polyester-Pongée-Material</li>
<li>-   Durchmesser ca. 140 cm</li>
<li>-   Stabiles Metallgestänge</li>
</ul>
</h3>
<h2 class="priceSize" style="text-align: center; color: #000000" ><br>
Preis: 24,90 €
</h2>

<h3>
<ul style="padding-top:30px">
<li>zzgl. Versandkosten: Deutschland: 4,95 € / EU: 14,95 € / Schweiz: 22,70 € </li>
</ul>
</h3>
</center>
<br>
</div>
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xrhtad58/)

I don't know if you are embedding all the CSS in the html for asking your question, but you should really put all of it in a separate stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="main_content"></div>
    <div id="banner"></div>
</div>
```

And a CSS here:
http://jsfiddle.net/uf67L7tp/